# how do I create a circular shadow effect with cairo?

Tags: python, cairo

I'm trying to enhance the graphical look of my application by giving the drawing a subtle shadow effect.  I'm using python and cairo drawing.

With the example code below I can draw an outer circle and an inner circle with the picture as shown.

[image: pic]

What I want to do is replace that outer circle with a shadow effect.

I guess that I need to use a lineargradient or a radialgradient but I can't find a good example for what I want to achieve.

Anybody point me in the correct direction please?

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Gdk
from gi.repository import GdkPixbuf

import cairo
import math

class MyWindow (Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title='MyWindow')

        darea = Gtk.DrawingArea()
        darea.connect('draw', self.on_draw)
        self.add(darea)

        self.width, self.height = self.get_size()

        filename = "/usr/share/backgrounds/Thingvellir_by_pattersa.jpg"

        if self.width > self.height:
            self.width = self.height
        else:
            self.height = self.width

        self.width = self.width
        self.height = self.height

        self.pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file(filename)
        self.pixbuf = self.pixbuf.scale_simple(self.width, self.width, GdkPixbuf.InterpType.BILINEAR)

    def on_draw(self, widget, cr):

        w = self.width
        h = self.height

        # draw outer circle
        cr.translate(w/2, h/2)
        cr.set_line_width(10)

        cr.set_source_rgb(0.7, 0.2, 0.0)
        cr.arc(0, 0, w/2, 0, 2*math.pi)
        cr.stroke_preserve()
        cr.stroke()

        # now reset the origin and set the picture to be the source
        cr.translate(-w/2, -h/2)

        Gdk.cairo_set_source_pixbuf(cr, self.pixbuf, 0, 0)

        # now reset the origin again and this time clip the pixbuf 
        cr.translate(w/2, h/2)

        cr.arc(0, 0, w/2.2, 0, 2*math.pi) # was 2.2
        cr.stroke_preserve()
        cr.clip()
        cr.paint()

win = MyWindow()
win.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Using Ubuntu 14.04 - Gtk+3.10, python3